# Can the Israeli Rabbanut Semicha Exams be written in English?

Tags: semicha

Does anyone know whether the Israeli Rabbanut exams can be written in English or another language other than Hebrew?

I understand that quotations might have to be written in Hebrew but does the Rabbanut allow to write majority in English as one might be limited in his modern Hebrew vocabulary.

Comment: It's difficult to imagine being able to master the material with insufficient Hebrew skills to write the exam.

Comment: I understand, but to paraphrase an shita for example instead of memorizing the the whole reason. There are people who can tell you this and that shita but when asked to write it in “modern Hebrew” they will struggle, especially in English teaching Yeshivas where they write in English and occasionally write something in Hebrew. Should they not accommodate to those who cannot write fully in Modern hebrew?

Comment: I doubt Modern Hebrew is required. Biblical or Mishnaic or Rabbinic Hebrew would surely do just fine. And personally I don't think they should accommodate such poorly planned Yeshivas, but assuredly the Rabbanut isn't seeking my opinions when forming their policies.

Comment: @double AA I found this http://www.smicha.co.il/gallery/mn_submenu-5.pdf page 3 bullet point 3 top page. What are your thoughts? I used google translate but even that could be wrong.

Comment: @Daniel Ross, it seems you have answered your own question, based on that link you provided special accommodations can be made,what accommodations that is up to them, so best place to address this question is to the Rabbanut

Comment: Don't know what happened to my last comment ,but if one looks at the link provided in the  comments that Hebrew is modern Hebrew and someone who knows gemara,Rishonim, poskim,may not fully understand all that language. However, many words should be familiar